# send a post httprequest to another server

Tags: laravel, api, post, httprequest

I am going to send a httprequest to special server that content api key.
Is there any way Except "guzzle" package?
I do not want to use an external package.

below is the code, which is not working in laravel

```
<?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://api.payping.ir/v1/pay');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
'authorization' => 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'content-type' => 'application/json',
'accept' => 'application/json'
));

$request->setBody('{
"payerName": "string",
"amount": 100,
"payerIdentity": "string",
"returnUrl": "Uri Format For Exam: (http(s)://payping.ir)",
"description": "string",
"clientRefId": "string"
}');

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
 } catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex; 
 }
```

Comment: Elaborate on "code is not work"...

Comment: can you elaborate your question?